# Windows form not responding and disappears when clicked on

Tags: c#, forms

I have a windows form and I added a method that takes a screenshot of the form using the Graphics class and then emails that screenshot (as a jpg) via SMTP. Now when I click on the print button (which invokes this method) it does everything it is supposed to do but then the form does not respond. If I click anywhere on the form the window disappears. My mouse will highlight the desktop icons I hover over with the form up. I have to kill it in task manager and reopen the form. Here is the problem code

```
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBoxSymptoms.Visible = false;
            txtSymptoms.Visible = true;
            foreach (object selectedItem in listBoxSymptoms.SelectedItems)
            {
                txtSymptoms.AppendText(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            SendEmail();

            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintImage);
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            pd.Print();
            SqlData.markPrinted(Convert.ToInt32(textBoxLogId.Text));
            pd.Dispose();
        }
```

Specifically, it is the pd.Print() function that is causing problems. Commented out, everything runs fine.

Comment: You're gonna have to show us some code to help ya out. Make sure you're disposing of your graphics properly, or perhaps you're hooking into the window's graphic device?  Perhaps you're disposing of that when you're not supposed to?

Comment: Yep. Look for what's going wrong as you step through the code in the debugger. Start at the point where the button click is detected, and step through to find the problem. Without your having posted any code, that's about the best anyone here can do to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Whats weird is it only does it when I publish it, it runs just fine in VS so I can't debug it that way.

Comment: Please take a look at the revised problem description above. Thanks!